# Does the word personne make the personal pronouns feminine?

Tags: grammaire, genre

I wrote the sentence below and was told it was incorrect because the word 'personne' is feminine and thus the personal pronouns afterwards should not be masculin even though I was talking about a man.

I wrote this:

> Parce qu'il y a une personne qui est végétarienne et il est très drôle...mais il est Américain

She said because we don't know it's a man it should be like this:

> Parce qu'il y a une personne qui est végétarienne et elle est très drôle... mais elle est Américaine

Comment: You can say "mais c'est un américain"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, pronouns referring to a substantive must agree with it. However, you can switch genders if the pronouns no more directly refer to the substantive but to something/someone of a different gender.

So the adjectives **must** agree with the substantive *personne* but the remaining clauses aren't required to agree if you know it's a man, they only need to agree with the pronoun used.

Unknown (or undisclosed) gender:

> Il y a une personne qui est végétarienne et elle est très drôle... mais elle est américaine.

Known gender:

> Donald Trump est une personne très intelligente et il est très drôle... mais il est américain.

Comment: 'It's not.." is not very clear. Can you make your answer a bit more clear? I still don't know which sentence is correct.

Comment: You are right, my answer was unclear. It is actually when we don't know the gender that the whole sentence need to stay feminine.

Comment: Yes it is very clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it must agree with the noun. DT n'est pas du tout une personne intélligente,  par contre. C'est un vraie dèrriere de cheval (blague traduits litéralement).

Comment: @jlliagre So to be clear, even if the person speaking knows the person is a man, if it's not clear in the sentence it counts as unknown gender?

Comment: The first sentence might still be used if the speaker knows the person gender but does not want to disclose it. @Lambie C'est pourtant un génie stable, non ;-)

Comment: Hasen,  the word defines the pronoun, feminine or masculine. C'est **un homme intélligent** mais ***une personne accablante***. You have to know which word the pronoun refers to and keep it masculine or feminine based on the word it refers to.

Comment: @jlliagre Oh....so I'm still not clear which is correct then. So my first sentence "Parce qu'il y a une personne qui est végétarienne et il est très drôle...mais il est Américain" was correct because I knew it was about a man? Even though the person I was talking to didn't....?

Comment: Your first sentence is odd because it starts with *Parce que* but doesn't look like an explanation. Even after dropping that part, your sentence is still unidiomatic, we would say *décousue* (rambling?). It might help if you give more context and explain to what question that sentence is expected to answer and what you would have written in English.

Comment: I guess if I knew it was a man I should have used "homme" or "quelqu'un".

Comment: @Hasen *“Quelqu’un”* would have been great, yes. Very natural and less awkward if you knew the person's gender.

Comment: Hasen, Even knowing it was a man, using *homme* or *quelqu'un* would have been great indeed, but not mandatory. *Une personne + adjective* can be used idiomatically when talking about a known male person. Same for other feminine words that apply to both men and women: *cet homme est une victime innocente*, *ce chanteur est une star internationale*.

Comment: All these subleties can be deliberate: if I want to talk about someone I know without disclosing his/her gender I may use _personne_ or _individu_

Comment: @jlliagre But could you say "cet homme, elle est une victime innocente" ?

Comment: No, you can't. That would be *cet homme, il est une victime innocente* or better *cet homme, c'est une victime innocente*.

Comment: @mouviciel Yes, *personne* can be use to avoid disclosing a person gender but there seems to be no documented example of *individu* used to refer to a woman. Source: [TLFi, Rem 1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/individu)

Comment: @jlliagre - Je suis sûr qu'on peut trouver un ou deux rapports de police dans lesquels l'auteur non identifié d'un méfait est qualifié d'_individu_.

Comment: @mouviciel Oui, bien sûr s'il s'agit d'un individu non identifié. Mais à partir du moment où l'on sait qu'il s'agit d'une femme, je ne pense pas qu'on utilise encore *un individu*. C'est l'avis du TLFi. On trouve quelques *une individu* inconnus des dictionnaires, [Une individu a fait irruption dans le magasin](http://www.sudinfo.be/185897/article/regions/sambre-meuse/actualite/2011-07-14/sombreffe-vol-de-400%E2%82%AC-au-nightday)